# Proof of knowledge of discrete log

Tags: hash, diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

Suppose that $P = pG = H(rK)G$, where $P$ is a point on an elliptic curve, $H$ is a hash function, $rK = kR$ is a shared secret between the party that knows $r$ and the party that knows $k$, and $G$ is a generator point.

Is there a way to prove that $P$ is well constructed (i.e., computed from the shared secret) and that someone who knows the shared secret can know $p$?

Comment: While this can be proven in zero knowledge using SNARKs, if that's what you want it should do. Although, it would not count as proof of knowledge for I know of no extractor which can extract a pre-image of a hash like that.

Comment: I am struggling to understand how would you prove such a thing if the witness you own as a prover is w.l.o.g $r$ but the secret that is used to compute the pre-image is actually $k$ which you do not know. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What do you want to prove about P? both parties know the shared secret the hash function and the generator G so they can both compute P independently

Comment: I think he wants to prove to third parties that the "other" party that knows the shared secret, can compute it. This `rK=kR` reminds me of Monero stealth addresses